# Setup Pinterest tag with Google Tag Manager doesn't work

Tags: reactjs, next.js, pinterest

I followed Pinterest steps to implement Pinterest tag on my Next.js website.
This is a no code implementation, I have Google Tag successfully installed on my website and I can see the events fired on the tag assistant.
However, the Pinterest tag isn't fired and I can't seem to find any exemple of React app with a Pinterest tag.

[image]

Because the previous method didn't work, I then tried the manual implementation but I don't think this this is the right code.

Manual implementation **in _document.js :**

```
<script 
        dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html:`
        !function(e){if(!window.pintrk){window.pintrk = function () {
          window.pintrk.queue.push(Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments))};var
            n=window.pintrk;n.queue=[],n.version="3.0";var
            t=document.createElement("script");t.async=!0,t.src=e;var
            r=document.getElementsByTagName("script")[0];
            r.parentNode.insertBefore(t,r)}}("https://s.pinimg.com/ct/core.js");
          pintrk('load', '<PINT_CODE>', {em: '<user_email_address>'});
          pintrk('page');
        ` }}
      />
```

Comment: This has nothing to do with Google Tag Manager, has it? If you have GTM installed, it makes more sense to implement pinterest via the built-in tag template in GTM.

Comment: No, this code is for the manual implementation. 
I followed this tutorial step by step but it doesn't work at all : https://www.analyticsmania.com/post/implement-pinterest-pixel-with-google-tag-manager/

Comment: Then I will remove the GTM tag.

Answer (score 0):

This is the solution I found:

```
<script 
      dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html:`
        !function(e){if(!window.pintrk){window.pintrk = function () {
        window.pintrk.queue.push(Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments))};var
          n=window.pintrk;n.queue=[],n.version="3.0";var
          t=document.createElement("script");t.async=!0,t.src=e;var
          r=document.getElementsByTagName("script")[0];
          r.parentNode.insertBefore(t,r)}}("https://s.pinimg.com/ct/core.js");
        pintrk('load', 'YOUR_CODE', {em: '<user_email_address>'});
        pintrk('page');
      ` }}
      />
```